# Access parent template from over-ridden version in Symfony / Twig

Tags: php, symfony, inheritance, twig, bundle

I have a third party bundle `OriginalBundle` and I want to customise some of the templates in it.

To achieve this, I have set up a Symfony bundle `MyCustomBundle` using [the override method shown in the Symfony docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/bundles/inheritance.html).

```
<?php

namespace My\CustomBundle;

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Bundle\Bundle;

class MyCustomBundle extends Bundle
{
    public function getParent()
    {
        return 'OriginalBundle';
    }
}
```

I am then using MyCustomBundle to create over-ride versions of some Twig templates from the OriginalBundle. However, I would like to be able to access the original template from my version (e.g. extend it) and just over-ride some of the blocks.

But, if I try to do something like this:

```
{# MyCustomBundle:Foo:bar.html.twig #}

{% extends 'OriginalBundle:Foo:bar.html.twig' %}

{% block xyz %}
    {# ... code in here ... #}
{% endblock %}
```

Then I get a white screen of death. I'm guessing it causes a recursion of some kind since Symfony is routing the `extends` call back to the customised file?

The original bundle's template looks like this:

```
{# OriginalBundle:Foo:bar.html.twig #}

{% block abc %}
    {% block xyz %}
        {# ... code in here ... #}
    {% endblock %}
{% endblock %}
```

So the question...

is there any way to access the original template file when an over-ridden version of the same template exists?

I'm basically looking for the Twig/template equivalent of `parent::doSomething()`.

Without this kind of access to the parent I find myself copying the entire original template file verbatim then updating a small part of it, which just feels wrong.

Comment: Can you show the original template you're extending from too?

Comment: Sure - I've edited the question to add an example

Comment: @caponica, I think you're looking for the 'embed' twig function.http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/embed.html

Comment: That's new to me - I'll take a look tomorrow. But not sure if it helps here since I'm trying to override a (third party) bundle's templates.

Comment: I don't think embed helps either... this scenario is a Symfony bundle override which routes usages of `OriginalBundle:Foo:bar.html.twig` to my custom version of the same file. What I'd like to know is if there's a way to access the original file (from my custom template), i.e. selectively ignore the over-ride from within the child's own templates.

Comment: I started a bounty, have you find out a solution in the meanwhile?

Comment: @gremo I did, look at my answer bellow

Answer (score 6):

There is a solution.
Symfony by default search for first matching resource and returns it.
To change this behaviour you need to specify some additional syntax. I use "!" to reach second match.

```
{% extends '!OriginalBundle:Foo:bar.html.twig' %}

{% block xyz %}
    {# ... code in here ... #}
{% endblock %}
```

Overriding file could be in `app/Resources/OriginalBundle/views/Foo/bar.html.twig`

To activate this system you need to override original Kernel to:

```
<?php
namespace Webility\Bundle\WebilityBundle\HttpKernel;

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel as BaseKernel;

abstract class Kernel extends BaseKernel
{
    public function getBundle($name, $first = true)
    {
        $get_next = false;
        if($name[0] == '!' && $first){
            $name = substr($name, 1);
            $first = false;
            $get_next = true;
        }

        $bundles = parent::getBundle($name, $first);

        if($get_next){
            return isset($bundles[1]) ? $bundles[1] : $bundles[0];
        } else {
            return $bundles;
        }
    }

    public function locateResource($name, $dir = null, $first = true)
    {
        $get_next = false;
        if($name[0] == '@' && $name[1] == '!' && $first){
            $name = '@'.substr($name, 2);
            $first = false;
            $get_next = true;
        }

        $files = parent::locateResource($name, $dir, $first);

        if($get_next){
            return isset($files[1]) ? $files[1] : $files[0];
        } else {
            return $files;
        }
    }
}
```

And use it in app/AppKernel.php

```
class AppKernel extends \Webility\Bundle\WebilityBundle\HttpKernel\Kernel
```

Comment: This is pretty neat! You can actually add your `getBundle` and `locateResource` methods to `app\AppKernel.php` directly, because `AppKernel` already extends the `Kernel` class.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to preserve the view of `xyz` block from the original bundle linked to the `FooController`, you have to type

```
{{ parent() }}
```

Otherwise, it's normal that if you redefine the block with nothing inside that you get an empty page.

Comment: I don't think that's it... I want to extend a template and redefine one of the blocks in it, but use the parent's block definitions for everything else. `parent()` is used to render a parent block, which is not what I'm trying to do. (Also, my redefined block is not empty - AFAIK the white screen is due to a symfony crash.)

Comment: can you show the path of original and customized controllers and twig files... with the code inside?

Comment: I don't think it matters... the references are correct and it works if I don't try to extend the original file or if I just extend a template without using Symfony's `getParent()` bundle override system. But when I try to use both I get stuck... and that's what the question is about.

Comment: I've updated it to show the over-ride class with the getParent() call. The paths are: `project\src\My\CustomBundle\MyCustomBundle.php`, `project\src\My\CustomBundle\Resources\views\Foo\bar.html.twig` and `project\vendor\third-party\original-bundle\Resources\views\Foo\bar.html.twig`

Comment: https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/overriding_templates.md

Comment: Usually i used the method b)

Comment: Exactly - method (b) there is what I'm trying to do, but it doesn't seem to like me putting an `{% extends 'OriginalBundle:x:y' %}` call into the over-ridden template file.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried just to do like this:

```
{# MyCustomBundle:Foo:bar.html.twig #}

{% block xyz %}
    {# ... code in here ... #}
{% endblock %}
```

Without the extend part ?

Answer (score 2):

in you want to preserve your 'extends' to original bundle, you have to use method a) so create app/Resources/original-bundle/views/layout.html.twig and/or app/Resources/original-bundle/views/Foo/bar.html.twig but by **pasting the whole code** of these templates vendors files because you want to reuse them( these paths override by default views of vendors) and then you can use your 'extends'

If you also want to override controllers of the vendors then use method b) : but even in this case you have to paste the code you want to reuse(and you will have to make an 'extends' on the new bundle)

Because I'm used to override controllers i use method b

Comment: Sorry, but this is not a solution. It's re-stating the problem. If I use method (a) from https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/overriding_templates.md then I have to paste the whole code from the original. This question is about how to extend the original file and just put the new bits in my version.

Comment: Ohhh..i've never seen a documentation for doing this...I think you can't because like as explained in fosuserbundle doc and  symfony doc, when you extend a template it looks first in app/Resources by default and then in src of your bundle, not in vendors... you can try in app/Resources without use 'extends' to directy write block xyz with your customization but i doubt that it works

Comment: ...hence me posting the question here! I would like to know if it's possible, and if so how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry but that ain't possible...always do method a) and b if you plan to override controllers

Answer (score 1):

I am actually searching for the same stuff.
My use case is as follows:

I have a website with a dashboard. I want to extend the dashboard with new data from my bundles.
Every bundle has its own data I want to place inside of some blocks in my dashboard.
The dashboard templates are not bound to any bundle so it should be accessible.

I would like to know how to inject blocks into templates without overloading any routing.

Edit: same stuff for navigation bar, e.g. - there should be a way of extending blocks without any problems so it would be easy to just extend main-website-navigation from bundles...

Answer (score 1):

This issue is caused by Symfony interpreting your template reference to `OriginalBundle` as `ChildBundle` as a result of bundle inheritance causing a function nesting level exception.

You can reference the parent's bundle template file using the following notation:

```
{% extends "@Original/Foo/bar.html.twig" %}
```

in replacement for:

```
{% extends "OriginalBundle:Foo:bar.html.twig" %}
```

Twig's `FilesystemLoader` splits the reference string into **namespace** (Original) and **path** (Foo/bar.html.twig). Namespace is your bundle name without the Bundle suffix. Full path for each namespace is resolved by concatenating default `<bundle_path>/Resources/views/` with supplied **path**.